# Is there a name for the style/genre of Sci-Fi using floating, illuminated technology elements?

Tags: technology, science-fiction-genre, terminology

[*Astral Chain*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3WqG1-7Ogk), [*Mass Effect*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6PJEmEHIaY), [*Halo 4*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krLOoBNpefc&t=123s) (with the Forerunner technology and weapons) and [*Black Panther*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXMNSvGMeAE) are all examples of Science Fiction that make use of floating, illuminated elements in their technology.  It gives the technology a futuristic, almost magical vibe.  Is their a term for this style of technology or genre of Science Fiction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Tron Lines**

From [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TronLines):

> When your technology isn't just bleeding-edge, but laser-edged, disruption-fielded-with-motorized-teeth high-tech. Power Glows, and now so does your tech. A common design scheme used for this glow is a series of lines along the edges or between panels of the machine. Others will have flat surfaces crossed by circuit-like lines that glow when activated, or have occasional pulses of light race down their length in tandem. Others have glowing components such as engines, weapon barrels, forcefield projectors and the like.

The examples at the bottom include *Mass Effect* and *Halo* Forerunners, which tells me that we're on the right track.

Other example IPs that I'm familiar with include: *Tron* (of course), *Atlantis: The Lost Empire, Treasure Planet, Zone of the Enders, Metroid*, and *Phantasy Star*.

Comment: And of course the eponymous _[Tron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron)_.

Comment: @Spencer Ha, guess I wasn't very clear. I just meant to point out that the OP's examples being included was a good sign. I'll edit in some examples into the actual answer in case that link ever dies.

Comment: Just want to do an extra shout out to Harabeck for absolutely nailing what was a slightly ineffable question.  Well done.